# Redux reducers adding nested objects to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

Banging my head against a wall here while making the UI for my app using React/Redux. The problem is that when my action is fired-off by the client mutating state it turns the piece of state I'm changing into a nested object.

In this case I am trying to change the piece of my state `loginForm` to either be `"login"` or `"signUp"`. When I fire off my action the prop `loginForm` (passed down into my component from state) looks like this: `this.props.loginForm.loginForm = "login"`.

client-side code:

```
import React from "react";

    import LoginForm from "../minor/LoginForm";

    const Login = React.createClass({

      displayForm(){

        if (this.props.loginForm === "login"){
          return <span>Login</span>
        } else if (this.props.loginForm === "signUp"){
          return <span>Sign Up</span>
        } else {
          console.log("meh")
        }

      },

      renderLogin(){
        this.props.chooseForm("login");
      },

      renderSignUp(){
        this.props.chooseForm("signUp");
      },

      render(){

        return(

            <div className="loginBox">
              <h1>Slots</h1>
              <button onClick={this.renderLogin}  name="login" >Login</button>
              <button onClick={this.renderSignUp} name="signUp" >Sign Up</button>            
              {this.displayForm()}
            </div>
          )
      }
    });

    export default Login;
```

userActions.js

```
export function chooseForm(form){
  console.log("choosing form")

  return {
    type: "CHOOSE_FORM",
    form
   }
}
```

userReducer.js

```
export function loginForm(state=null, action){

  switch(action.type){

  case "CHOOSE_FORM":

    return {...state, loginForm: action.form };


  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

The aim here is to then display the proper component associated with the value of `this.prop.loginForm` which is unachievable due to my issue stated above.

**Update**

mainReducer.js (combinedReducer)

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import {routerReducer} from "react-router-redux";

// reducers
import { loginStatus, loginForm }from "./userReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ loginStatus, loginForm, routing:      routerReducer});

 export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: There aren't enough details-but check your combined reducers. I assume you're not using react-redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `loginForm` reducer is a [slice reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) you should just return the value for that slice of state, not the entire state, ie you should return the `form` value:

```
case "CHOOSE_FORM": 
    return action.form;
```

Which would replace the `loginForm` state key with `"login"` or `"signUp"` when handling those actions.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm going to make an educated guess and say this looks like it could be a problem within a combinedReducers file.  If you are using combineReducers read on...

It could be that within that you are setting the Redux state to something like:

```
loginForm: userReducer
// so the Redux state would be set have a property in it
// 'loginForm' set to {loginForm:'login'}
```

**The solution:**

Modify your combineReducers to:

```
loginForm: userReducer.loginForm
```

Comment: Thanks for the educated guess. I updated my question to include my equivalent of `combineRecuders`.  If I am understanding you correctly I need to use dot notation to get those methods to work without making my state a bunch of nested objects. Will test out, thank you.